# Are there any SageMaker resources on how to perform training in a distributed manner with a custom algorithm?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I've seen that SageMaker's built in algorithms support distributed training. However, I haven't found any documentation for how to structure my data and/or my image containing the custom algorithm so that training can be done in a distributed manner. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this has already been discussed here: [AWS Sagemaker custom user algorithms: how to take advantage of extra instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507471/aws-sagemaker-custom-user-algorithms-how-to-take-advantage-of-extra-instances)

Basically, you need to managed communication between the different containers. You'll find some pointers here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo.html#your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container-dist-training

Alternatively, you could use one of the built-in algos (object classification, detection, segmentation) or one of the built-in DL environments (TF, MXNet, etc.). Is there any specific reason why you use a custom container?